# Create "Template" XCode project that automaticly adds git-submodules etc?

Tags: xcode, macos, git, git-submodules

I have a few xcode projects (static libraries) that I include in several other projects through the use of git-submodules. This works great and I like this way of sharing code between projects. However, since I am adding some of these libraries to pretty much every new project I create I would like to streamline this process somehow. Create some sort of "template" of which I can base all my projects.

I would like some way to automaticly go through these steps:

1. Create a new project called X
2. Add a fixed (or dynamic) list of submodules
3. Have the added submodules automaticly added to the Xcode-project

Is it possible to create a script for this? With a syntax like:

fooproj -n "Bar" -s "foundation, coredata, uikit"

(where Bar is the name of the new project and foundation, coredata and uikit would be the submodules to add)

Or is there some other way I could streamline this process?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Xcode Templates? They're quite powerful and are the basis of how Xcode currently sets up new projects. Here are a few links on how to create Xcode templates:

[NSScreencast](http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/68-xcode-project-templates), [bob Mccune's blog](http://www.bobmccune.com/2012/03/04/creating-custom-xcode-4-file-templates/), [meandmark.com](http://meandmark.com/blog/2011/11/creating-custom-xcode-4-file-templates/)

And a few sample resources to get you started:

[Xcode 5 project templates](https://github.com/reidmain/Xcode-5-Project-Templates) and [Minimal templates](https://github.com/borealkiss/Minimal-Template)

They're confusing at first, now I couldn't live without them. Xcode templates are a huge time-saver.